# tapped link on a phone opens image at bottom of page, not at link position

Tags: html, css, popup

The links on my site work great as mouse overs and *almost* great as tapped links on a phone except that on a phone, the images don't open beside the link--they open at the very bottom of the long page, *below the footer*. If I try to use a CSS centering code (and I've tried several) it ruins the position of the image on a desktop. I would greatly appreciate a solution. The site: https://coachcaudlecares.org/llltest.html

Relevant CSS:

```
#pup {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:999; /* aaaalways on top*/
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px dashed grey;
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  font-size: 0.95em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

I apologize but I can't figure out how to enter the correct coding to show a sample of the popup in a paragraph, but you can easily find it on the page. Thank you to anyone who can help.

Comment: The tapped photos show OK near the relevant red word on my real IOS/iPad (both portrait and landscape) but they turn up at the bottom of the page on the Chrome iPad emulator. Do you see the problem on real iPhones etc as well as on the emulator? Sorry I don't have a phone to try it on at the moment.

Comment: Yes, I see the problem on an iPhone and a Samsung. I've been told they show up correctly on an iPad.

Comment: I see where the problem starts and have put findings so far in an answer. It may not lead to a full solution, we need to try the experiment I've suggested first.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code in the imported JS file which does the creation and positioning of the popups I can see that it is testing for a touch device like this:

```
var deviceAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
        return deviceAgent.match(/(iphone|ipod|ipad|android|blackberry|iemobile|opera m(ob|in)i|vodafone)/) !== null);
```

This is not a safe way to test for anything as browsers can write what they like as the device agent.

For example, on a real iPad (IOS 14) I see this returned:

> mozilla/5.0 (macintosh; intel mac os x 10_15_6) applewebkit/605.1.15 (khtml, like gecko) version/14.0.3 safari/605.1.15

No mention of 'ipad' so the code thinks it's got a non-touch device and does the normal positioning for a desktop. Indeed, on a real iPad I see the popup in the right place.

Digging a bit deeper I can see that there are some ' historic' calls to jquery and jquerymobile in the head section of your website. But they are called over http and the site has been called over https so they are not loaded. You should be seeing errors in your browser's dev console. A more recent version of jquery is loaded over https.

Now, I cannot tell whether the absence of the mobile version actually has any affect, but I can see in the popup's JS that the X and Y positions of the 'mouse' seem not to be read if the system thinks the device is actually a touch one. So the absolutely positioned popup is put where the page has got to at the time, i.e. the very end.

For a start could you comment out the deviceAgent code given above and return false. Then try on real touch devices, especially Samsung and iPhone, to see what happens.

(Obviously if that popup js file is used by another, real site, take a copy and use that!).

Comment: Thank you, this sounds like a great trial, but I can't find that js file you're referring to. :( I have too many and I've searched all of them without success in finding that code. Can you tell me the name of it? By the way, I did update all the http sites to https for the most recent versions. Don't know if that matters since I may not be using them; they were early attempts.

Comment: Your test site now has more problems - you are loading jquery twice and also jquery mobile. Could you take out the two references to the earlier (1....) versions. It's worth looking in the head section of your site using your browser dev tools to see the things that are being loaded. The version of the popup that you have loaded you will see there, it's called /nhpup_1.1.js

Comment: Commenting out that code did cause the links to display differently, but now they're at the top of the page in a fixed position instead of the bottom. Any ideas how to solve that? You're really helping and I'm looking further into the other issues.

Comment: Upon testing, it turns out that early jquery-1.11.1.min.js is necessary to make the nhpup_1.1.js work. Dev tool doesn't like the nhpup script, though, even though it works, especially this: "nhpup.onTouchDevice is not a function."

Comment: So is the more recent jquery (version 3....) now removed? The site was working on my ipad and laptop with the more recent version.

Comment: Yes, does it not work anymore on your ipad or laptop? If so, I'll put it back.

Comment: Still working on my laptop (WIndows10, Edge) but now on my iPad (IOS14, Safari) the photo is top left. At least that's consistent with others mobiles!However, on both the links have gone to blue not red, though the message at the top still says hover over the red.

Comment: I know. It has to do with the js (http/https). When I go back to http, the links return to red and navigation to white, but my mouse overs disappear. It's getting worse. I will uncomment the nhpup code to see if they return. But then I'm starting over.